# error in using class in C++ (no match for call to Class_name)

Tags: c++, class

When I try compiling the code below, I got the error following:

> homework3_test.cpp:111:25: error: no match for call to ‘(PowerN) (int&)’
>     power_three(test_power2);

PowerN is a class.

```
class PowerN{
    public:
    static int i;
    PowerN(int a);  
};
```

power_three is defined as

> PowerN power_three(3);

this one is fine while "3" is an integer. But for the following three integer variable:

> int test_power1, test_power2, test_power3;

it returns the error. So why are they different? Is it the reason that int test_power1 does not have a value so it becomes a int& ? How may I solve that?

below is the code of PowerN

```
PowerN::PowerN(int a){

    int b=0;
    if (i>0){
        a = pow(b,(i-1));
    }
    else {
        b=a;
    }
    i= i+1;
}
```

Update:
PowerN need to change the value of the 2nd, 3rd,4th integer it takes, below is the requirement:

PowerN's constructor takes a single integer, N. Every time the function operator of an instance of PowerN is called, it changes the value of its argument to N**x, where x is the number of times the function operator was called. For example:

```
int x;

PowerN power_three(3);

power_three(x);//x will now be 1

power_three(x);//x will now be 3

power_three(x);//x will now be 9
```

The code that reproduces error is:

homework3_test.cpp:111:25: error: no match for call to ‘(PowerN) (int&)’

```
power_three(test_power2);
```

Comment: Could you post some minimal code sample that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Also what is the error that you are having?

Comment: Hi I updated some requirement of the Class PowerN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears in the code in your update:

```
int x;
PowerN power_three(3);
power_three(x);//x will now be 1
```

The last line attempts to call `PowerN::operator()`. However you did not define an `operator()`. The error message is a bit cryptic, but it is saying that it looked for `PowerN::operator()(int &)` and did not find it.

I don't know what you are imagining will happen that would result in "x will now be 1".  It almost seems as if you are trying to call the constructor again on an object that already exists.  That is not legal; and even if it were, the syntax would be something different.

Perhaps you should move some of the code currently in your constructor into a member function (say `calculate(int &)`, and then do:

```
PowerN power_three(3);
power_three.calculate(x);
```

Comment: I think that might be the case! Thx. But some other error occurs which even not gives where the error is.

Comment: sth like that: 64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /tmp/ccAyXwzE.o: bad reloc address 0x0 in section `.data' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
2014-04-02

Comment: Post the exact code that gives the error (preferably a complete program), along with the exact error.

Comment: it even did not tell me where the error is . it just says:t.cpp:(.text+0x56e): undefined reference to `std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > apply<PowerN>(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, PowerN)'
/tmp/ccTmz7IN.o:homework3_test.cpp:(.text+0x56e): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > apply<PowerN>(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, PowerN)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /tmp/ccTmz7IN.o: bad reloc address 0x0 in section `.data'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: You have to post the exact program giving the error, in its entirety. We don't have a crystal ball

Comment: That's a vector message but you don't have any vectors in the code shown so far.